# How to run gitlab stage periodically?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

How can I run a gitlab stage periodically? I am aware of pipeline schedules documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html. I am only interested in running a particular test stage of a branch. The issue is the branch I want to target has a lot of other stages involved with it. One option might be introducing a variable in the script portion that says if true then execute the script. However, this can be cumbersome and require a lot of changes to all the stages of the ci file for that particular branch under consideration.

Comment: Extracting out the stage as a separate pipeline and using [trigger pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html) to keep it together with existing pipeline. Furthermore, schedule extracted standalone pipeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control when your jobs run using the `only/except` keywords, or the more advanced `rules` keyword along with the pipeline source variable.

Example with `only`:

```
scheduled_test:
  stage: tests
  image: my_image:latest
  only:
    - schedules
  script:
    - ./run_some_things.sh
```

The `only` keyword lets you define some conditions that mean "this job only runs if these conditions are true", and offers a shorthand to check the source of the pipeline. `schedules` means that the pipeline was started from a schedule rather than a push, trigger, etc. The `except` keyword is just the opposite. If it had `except: schedules` the job would always run except if it was scheduled. You can see the full documentation for the `only/except` keywords here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-basic

As of Gitlab version 12.3, the `rules` keyword extends the possibilities of the `only/except` options. We could get the same result from the example above like this:

```
scheduled_test:
  stage: tests
  image: my_image:latest
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"'
      when: always
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      when: never
```

In this example, we check the predefined variable `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` to see what started this pipeline. If it's "schedule", we always run this job. As an example, if the source is "push" (so the pipeline was started by a `git push` command), this job will never run. With the `rules` keyword, all `if` statements are OR'ed together, so the example above reads, `if the source is schedule, always run OR if the source is a push, never run`. However, you can AND multiple conditionals together in the same if:

```
rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $MY_CUSTOM_VARIABLE == true'
    when: manual
```

You can read the full documentation for the `rules` keyword here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using except keyword (due to gitlab version) and it seems to be working in my testing so far.

Comment: Yea, `only` and `except` were the only way to do these things until `rules` came along with more options. Glad you got it working though!