# Run only specific stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have 4 stages. But one stage is independent. I just want to run it by ever week. I could not find any information about running a single stage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run gitlab stage periodically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65910754/how-to-run-gitlab-stage-periodically)

Comment: See the `rules` guidance in the accepted answer. You can then use similar rules to disallow other stages for scheduled builds